# SQL Server WHERE clause - Advice

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Am trying to get results in a single SQL script that will cover several options. Have finally got the results I need with this.

```
where 
(RTRIM(FMLS.REGION)) IN (@Region) and 
(RTRIM(FMB0.COUNTRY))IN (@Country) and 
(RTRIM(FMB0.SITECODE)) IN (@Site) and 
(RTRIM(FMB0.BLDGCODE)) IN (@Building) and 
( 
 ( 
  (RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) NOT IN ('A-OFF-AS','A-WKS-AS') AND ((RTRIM(FMA0.SPCODE) <> '') AND (FMA0.SPCODE IS NOT NULL))) 
            AND 
  (RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) NOT LIKE 'CR-%' AND ((RTRIM(FMA0.SPCODE) <> '') AND (FMA0.SPCODE IS NOT NULL))) 
 ) 
 OR 
 ( 
  (RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) = 'A-OFF-AS' AND RTRIM(FMA0.SPCODE) NOT LIKE 'A-OFF-%') OR 
  (RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) = 'A-WKS-AS' AND RTRIM(FMA0.SPCODE) NOT LIKE 'A-WKS-%')OR 
  (RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) LIKE 'CR-%' AND RTRIM(FMA0.SPCODE) NOT LIKE 'CR-%') 
  ) 
)
```

But what concerns me is the need for the AND in these two lines

```
  (RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) NOT IN ('A-OFF-AS','A-WKS-AS') AND ((RTRIM(FMA0.SPCODE) <> '') AND (FMA0.SPCODE IS NOT NULL))) 
            AND 
  (RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) NOT LIKE 'CR-%' AND ((RTRIM(FMA0.SPCODE) <> '') AND (FMA0.SPCODE IS NOT NULL)))
```

where I would have thought it should be an OR as I want to get results where FMA0.SPCODE is blank OR null for both lines, like this

```
  (RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) NOT IN ('A-OFF-AS','A-WKS-AS') AND ((RTRIM(FMA0.SPCODE) <> '') OR (FMA0.SPCODE IS NOT NULL))) 
            OR 
  (RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) NOT LIKE 'CR-%' AND ((RTRIM(FMA0.SPCODE) <> '') OR (FMA0.SPCODE IS NOT NULL)))
```

But if I do this I get the wrong results. I can't figure it out, perhaps have been looking at this too long or have brackets in the wrong place, but I can't see what I am doing wrong.....please help, its driving me mad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AND` and `OR` with negative expressions is a bit complicated logically.  If you said:

```
SPACETYPE NOT IN ('A-OFF-AS','A-WKS-AS') OR SPACETYPE NOT LIKE 'CR-%'
```

Then *all* `SPACETYPE` would pass this test.  Consider a value such as `'THIS'`, it is not in the first list, so it would be ok.  Consider a value such as `'A-OFF-AS'`.  It *is* in the first list, so the first condition fails.  So, go to the second condition.  No match, so it passes.  You can try this on a lot of different values and you'll find that the `OR` will pass everything.  In fact, the above logic is equivalent to:

```
NOT (SPACETYPE IN ('A-OFF-AS','A-WKS-AS') AND SPACETYPE LIKE 'CR-%')
```

Clearly the `AND` is never true, so the `NOT` is false.  (NOTE:  this discussion is ignoring `NULL` values.)

Hence, the `OR` doesn't work.  Happily for you, the `AND` does do what you want.  You just need to get used to the intricacies of boolean logic.